# Includes files from outside the src directory

Tags: .net-core, config, csproj

I have a Solution Architecture like this :

[image: Architecture]

In my src folder, I have a Console App Project which currently serve as an UI. It's the startup project.

When I run my solution, I'm not able to reach the json files located on the config directory, out of my src directory. Because, while on Debug mode, every projects are built separately and the console projects output does not contain the json files.

What I want, if it's possible, is to have inside my output directory of the console project a "config" directory populated with the json files copied to it.

To achieve it, I have tried to add this to the .csproj of my console project :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\config\**\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Basically, I'm trying to go through the hierarchy of the solution and copy the json files if newer to the output of my project. But this is not as simple as that, it does not work.

How can I copy the json files to the output directory of my project ?

**EDIT 1 :**

Here is the structure of my solution with the csproj visibles :

[image: structure]

Comment: Can you show the structure in src (just to see csproj)?

Comment: @vernou sure, I updated my post

Comment: Do the physic folder tree is the same as the solution folder tree? (With Visual Studio, it's possible to have a virtual folder).

Comment: The src directory is the same, yes. But I struggled to add the config folder to the physic folder so I created it as a virtual one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to fix it.

So first I created the directory "config" physically next to my "src" directory.

Then I added the 2 jsons files to the Solution through Visual Studio. It created a directory with a default name, I renamed it as "config". So I have the exact same structure than I had on my screenshots, but there is the exact same structure physically.

After that, everything worked fine. When I was building my project, I had the json files in the output directory.

But they were at the root directory, and I wanted them to be in a "config" directory. So I modified my csproj as following :

```
<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\config\AppSettings.json" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)/config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\config\DatabaseSettings.json" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)/config" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyCustomContentOnPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\config\AppSettings.json" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)/config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\config\DatabaseSettings.json" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)/config" />
  </Target>
```

And now, that's perfect ! I have a config directory in my output directory as intended.

Thanks for your help anyway.